# Error message for undefined custom library reference

Tags: c, lua

I am writing a Lua library in C for an embedded system.  Is there a way to throw a meaningful error if the script writer tries to call a library function that is not defined in the library?

Right now if (for instance) the script has a spelling mistake, where
ez.RS232opn()
is called instead of the proper:
ez.RS232open() function,

Lua throws a cryptic error of "attempt to call a nil value"

In my library, I would like to throw an error such as "Invalid ez Library function name: RS232opn"

I do understand why the cryptic error is thrown (because the library is actually a Table), but it doesn't mean much to our developers, who are relatively new to Lua.

Forgive me if I missed something, but I searched the Lua documentation and also stackoverflow and Google and couldn't find any clues.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which version of Lua are you using? In Lua 5.1 and 5.2 the message is `attempt to call field 'RS232opn' (a nil value)`. In Lua 5.3+, the message is `attempt to call a nil value (field 'RS232opn')`. Both mention the misspelled name.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do to make it give a customized error for bad function calls is to use regular expressions, called Patterns in Lua. Have it search nil value calls with an ending () and return that they're an invalid function.

Lua.org Patterns page
https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html

Answer (score 1):

Calling nil values is not allowed in Lua as it does not make any sense.

> Lua throws a cryptic error of "attempt to call a nil value"

You usually get a line number, the name and if it is local or global scope.
That's all information you need.

> it doesn't mean much to our developers, who are relatively new to Lua.

This message should make sense to anyone who read the Lua manual and spent like an hour programming Lua. It is rather self explanatory.

Autocompletion helps to avoid typos in APIs btw.

You could hack something together using metamethods but that's ugly and not necessary.
There is only a hand full of error messages. Any Lua developer must know them anyway. So why replace them by another text?

Your

> "Invalid ez Library function name: RS232opn"

bears less information than Lua's

> input:245 attempt to call a nil value (field 'RS232opn')

btw.

Comment: Our target audience has little to no Lua experience--most are hardware engineers, not software engineers.  Therefore error messages need to be descriptive.  Honestly, I've been a developer for 30+ years using more languages than I can count and "attempt to call a nil value" totally confused me (I understand it now but its not intuitive).  Hence the reason for needing a better error message.  Simply-put, if my boss [who's a hardware guy, not a software guy] doesn't understand the error message then it's not acceptable.

Comment: @RobertG It is if you know the very basics of Lua. It doesn't get any simpler. nil is like the most important and common type in Lua. Everyone usinging Lua must know it. The Lua compiler tells you what you did wrong, where you did it and which name you used. What else could any developer wish for? Even your target audience should read the Lua manual befor using your Lua API...  Lua APIs are for Lua developers. Not for monkeys. Someone with 30+ years of experience should have no problems to convey that. But as I said you still can use metatables or translate the error message.